# Bluetooth stopped working on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

Bluetooth was working fine on my Bluetooth stopped working on Raspberry Pi 4 and then just it stopped turning on even on the GUI.

The `rfkill` list shows the following results:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

This is the result for `hciconfig -a`:

```
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: DC:A6:32:D3:66:2D  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        UP RUNNING
        RX bytes:725 acl:0 sco:0 events:40 errors:0
        TX bytes:456 acl:0 sco:0 commands:40 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT
        Name: 'BCM43455 37.4MHz Raspberry Pi 3+-0190'
        Class: 0x000000
        Service Classes: Unspecified
        Device Class: Miscellaneous,
        HCI Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Revision: 0x17e
        LMP Version: 5.0 (0x9)  Subversion: 0x6119
        Manufacturer: Cypress Semiconductor (305)
```

I also tried reinstalling some bluetooth packages but nothing seems to work.

Also this the result for `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`:

```
Job for bluetooth.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status bluetooth.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Output from`systemctl status bluetooth.service`:

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service 
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service.d 
           └─override.conf 
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-12-24 23:43:08 EET; 19h ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
  Process: 820 ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --debug -n (code=exited, status=203/EXEC) 
 Main PID: 820 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC) CPU: 22ms

Dec 24 23:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service... 
Dec 24 23:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[820]: bluetooth.service: Failed to locate executable /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd: No such file or directory 
Dec 24 23:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[820]: bluetooth.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd: No such file or directory 
Dec 24 23:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC 
Dec 24 23:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 24 23:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Bluetooth service
```

This what happens when I try to power on bluetooth using sudo bluetoothctl power on

```
No default controller available
```

I also tried `sudo bluetoothctl`.

What can I do to make it work again?

Comment: see where it says *See "systemctl status bluetooth.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.* - did you do that?

Comment: bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-12-24 23:43:08 EET; 19h ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
    Process: 820 ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --debug -n (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 820 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 22ms

Comment: Dec 24 23:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Dec 24 23:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[820]: bluetooth.service: Failed to locate executable /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd: No such file or directory
Dec 24 23:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[820]: bluetooth.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd: No such file or directory
Dec 24 23:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Dec 24 23:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Comment: Dec 24 23:43:08 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start Bluetooth service.
@JaromandaX

Comment: output like that is unreadable in comments ... put that output in the question where it's at least possible to make it readable

Comment: The posted sytemctl output is reporting that the `bluetoothd` executable is missing. The output on my system is showing it at `/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd`. Did the path accidentally get changed when then non-default options of `--debug -n` got added?